# Why is the last element of my multi dimensional array unclickable?

Tags: javascript

```
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
```

```
        var anArray = [["A1","B1","C1"],
                     ["A2","B2","C2"],
                     ["A3","B3","C3"],
                     ["A4","B4","C4"],
                     ["A5","B5","C5"],
                     ["A1","B1","C1"],
                     ["A2","B2","C2"],
                     ["A3","B3","C3"],
                     ["A4","B4","C4"],
                     ["A5","B5","C5"]]; //last element of array was unclickable, I assumed that the last element of the array was null? what will I do to click the last element of array?

            var tables = document.getElementById("table");




       for(var i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++)
       {
           // create a new row
           var newRow = table.insertRow(tables.length);

            console.log(newRow);
           for(var j = 0; j < anArray[i].length; j++)
           {
               // create a new cell
                cell = newRow.insertCell(j);

               // add value to the cell
               cell.innerHTML = anArray[i][j];

            tables.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function(){

            rIndex = this.parentElement.rowIndex+1;
                    cIndex = this.cellIndex;
                    console.log("Row : "+rIndex+" , Cell : "+cIndex);







                }

               }
           }
```

I did everything I could, I want to create a list of multidimensional arrays on javascript and print the output on HTML at the same time, clicking the table cells and I did, but there was a problem: the last element of anArray turned out null because it was unclickable. What did I do wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your table has *an extra row* at the top, here:

```
<tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
</tr>
```

So when you access `tables.rows[i]`, you're actually accessing the `anArray` item at index `i - 1`.

For example, when `i = 2`, you add a listener to all cells of `["A2", "B2", "C2"]` - the *second* row, not the third. As a result, at the end, the last row does not get any listeners attached.

Instead of accessing the newly created row with `table.rows[i]`, consider referencing the created row with the `newRow` variable already in scope (and declare it with `const` so that it's block scoped):

```js
var anArray = [
  ["A1", "B1", "C1"],
  ["A2", "B2", "C2"],
  ["A3", "B3", "C3"],
  ["A4", "B4", "C4"],
  ["A5", "B5", "C5"],
  ["A1", "B1", "C1"],
  ["A2", "B2", "C2"],
  ["A3", "B3", "C3"],
  ["A4", "B4", "C4"],
  ["A5", "B5", "C5"]
]; //last element of array was unclickable, I assumed that the last element of the array was null? what will I do to click the last element of array?

var tables = document.getElementById("table");

for (let i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
  // create a new row
  const newRow = table.insertRow(tables.length);
  for (let j = 0; j < anArray[i].length; j++) {
    // create a new cell
    cell = newRow.insertCell(j);
    // add value to the cell
    cell.innerHTML = anArray[i][j];
    newRow.cells[j].onclick = function() {
      rIndex = this.parentElement.rowIndex + 1;
      cIndex = this.cellIndex;
      console.log("Row : " + rIndex + " , Cell : " + cIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or, more concisely, with `forEach`:

```js
var anArray = [
  ["A1", "B1", "C1"],
  ["A2", "B2", "C2"],
  ["A3", "B3", "C3"],
  ["A4", "B4", "C4"],
  ["A5", "B5", "C5"],
  ["A1", "B1", "C1"],
  ["A2", "B2", "C2"],
  ["A3", "B3", "C3"],
  ["A4", "B4", "C4"],
  ["A5", "B5", "C5"]
]; //last element of array was unclickable, I assumed that the last element of the array was null? what will I do to click the last element of array?

const table = document.getElementById("table");
anArray.forEach((subarr, rowIndex) => {
  const tr = table.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
  subarr.forEach((content, cellIndex) => {
    const td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    td.textContent = content;
    td.onclick = () => console.log("Row : " + (rowIndex + 2) + " , Cell : " + (cellIndex + 2));
  });
});
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You are a wizard, my friend, I did not noticed that though. thanks for correcting me :D